One frame flyout bug on a tab bar menu
While bulding my simple app I´ve notice a little bug (dont know if its a feature or not) showing a flyout menu on few frames in only tab bar menu app in case of user decided to do back one step
https://youtube.com/shorts/XcPQN9AkTFY?feature=share
Here is my code I used in MainViewModel:
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace MauiApp1.ViewModel;
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [RelayCommand]
    async Task AddChat()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(NewChatPage));
    }
}

AppShell.xaml.cs:
namespace MauiApp1
{
    public partial class AppShell : Shell
    {
        public AppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(NewChatPage), typeof(NewChatPage));
        }
    }
}

MauiProgram.cs:
namespace MauiApp1.Other
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                    fonts.AddFont("Helvetica-Bold.ttf", "Helveticabold");
                });

#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<NewChatPage>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<NewChatViewModel>();
            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}

I had tried to search for this problem but I didn´t find anything


While bulding my simple app I´ve notice a little bug (dont know if its a feature or not) showing a flyout menu on few frames in only tab bar menu app in case of user decided to do back one step

No, it's not a feature. And we reproduced it like your short video show. You can report it on MAUI issue GitHub. Let the developers know and deal with it.
Update:
I noticed that you post the issue on GitHub. You can trace it to see if any update.
